# Collection of subsets with adding one element property

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a collection of subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ such that for any set $A\in\mathcal{F}$, there exists $B\not\in \mathcal{F}$ such that $A\subset B\subseteq\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ and $|B|=|A|+1$. What is the maximum size of $\mathcal{F}$?

One bound is that $\mathcal{F}$ can be of size at least $2^{n-1}$. Indeed, if $n$ is even, put all subsets of odd size in $\mathcal{F}$ (and vice versa if $n$ is odd.) And of course $\mathcal{F}$ is of size no more than $2^n$, the number of subsets of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

Any better upper/lower bounds?

Comment: It's hardly worth a comment, but $2^n-1$ is an upper bound, and $2^{n-1}+n-2$ is a lower bound.

Comment: bof: how do you get $2^{n-1}+n-2$?

Comment: @ColinMcQuillan $\mathcal F=\{X\subset\{1,2,\dots,n\}:(|X|=n-1\text{ AND }1\in X)\text{ OR }(|X|\lt n-1\text{ AND }1\notin X)\}$

Comment: @bof $2^{n-1}+n-2$ is not a very good lower bound; for $n=7$ it's easy to get $|\mathcal F|=75$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess for the correct answer is $(1-\Theta(1/n)) 2^n$, though I can't quite show that.

Here is a probabilistic construction that gives $(1-O(\log n/n))2^n$. The $\log n$ can probably be removed. Let $0 \leq w < n$. Choose some probability $p$, and put each $x \in \binom{n}{w+1}$ in a set $S_{w+1}$ with probability $p$. The probability that some $y \in \binom{n}{w}$ doesn't get covered by some set in $S_{w+1}$ is $(1-p)^{n-w}$, and we put all these into some set $T_w$. We will later throw away both $S_{w+1}$ and $T_w$. The expected size of both sets together is $p\binom{n}{w+1} + (1-p)^{n-w} \binom{n}{w}$, and there is some choice achieving this. Choosing $p = \log(n-w)/(n-w)$, we get $(1-p)^{n-w} \approx 1/(n-w) < p$. When $w \leq (1-\epsilon) n$ (for some arbitrary constant $0 < \epsilon < 1/2$), $p  \leq \log n/(\epsilon n)$. Hence by taking all sets of weight at most $(1-\epsilon) n$ and removing all $T_w$ and $S_{w+1}$, we get a set satisfying your property whose density is $1-\log n/(\epsilon n)$. (The total weight of sets of weight more than $(1-\epsilon) n$ is exponentially small.)

In order to remove the $\log n$, we can try to intelligently choose $S_{w+1}$. The calculation below shows that in order to obtain $T_w = \emptyset$ we need $|S_{w+1}| \geq 1/(n-w) \binom{n}{w+1}$, and I imagine that there is a construction almost achieving this. Such a construction would give a family of size $(1-O(1/n))2^n$.

Here is an upper bound of $(1-\Omega(1/n))2^n$. Given a family $\mathcal{F}$, let $S_w = \mathcal{F} \cap \binom{n}{w}$ belongs to the family. Since each set in $\binom{n}{w+1}$ covers at most $w+1$ sets in $S_w$, at least $|S_w|/(w+1)$ sets must be omitted from the family. If $|S_w| = \alpha \binom{n}{w}$ then
$$ \frac{|S_w|}{w+1} = \frac{\alpha}{n-w} \binom{n}{w+1}. $$
Hence for $w < (1-\epsilon)n$ (for some arbitrary constant $0 < \epsilon < 1/2$), either $|S_w| < (1/2) \binom{n}{w}$ or $|S_{w+1}| < (1-1/(2\epsilon n)) \binom{n}{w+1}$ (we could choose a better cutoff instead of $1/2$ to get better constants). In total, again using the fact that large sets are an exponentially small fraction of all sets, we get that $|\mathcal{F}| \leq (1-\Omega(1/n))2^n$.

Comment: For your upper bound, just noting that each set covers at most $n$ sets (regardless of $w$) would suffice to show an upper bound of $(1-1/n)2^n$, right?

Comment: Right, that would have been enough. I must have been a little tired.

Comment: No worries. :) Your probabilistic construction looks very nice. Could you please elaborate on why $(1-p)^{n-w}\approx 1/(n-w)$, and $p\leq\log n/(\epsilon n)$? I'm not very familiar with these estimates.

Comment: Well, $(1-p)^{n-w} = (1-\log(n-w)/(n-w))^{n-w} \approx e^{-\log(n-w)} = 1/(n-w)$, using the estimate $(1-x/n)^n \approx e^{-x}$. The other estimate follows directly from $w \leq (1-\epsilon) n$, by upper bounding the numerator (using $w \geq 0$) and lower bounding the denominator.